# Remove Clipping From GraphicsContext

Tags: java, javafx

This is probably the easiest question ever. I have a JavaFx `Canvas` setup like this:

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 300);
    GraphicsContext context = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    // make a big rectangle
    context.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    context.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);

    // clip
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    context.closePath();
    context.clip();

    // so now this draws a clipped smaller rectangle
    context.setFill(Color.RED);
    context.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);

    context.removeClip(); // ???

    // remove clip so this white rectangle is shown
    context.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    context.setLineWidth(3);
    context.strokeRect(75, 75, 150, 150);
```

I tried `GraphicsContext#restore()` (which restores everything but the clipping and creating a rectangular path starting at 0|0 and with the canvas's size and calling `clip()` again.

How do I remove clipping from a `GraphicsContext`?

Comment: I don't use canvas much, so I'm not certain about this, but it looks like [`context.restore()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#restore--) should remove the clip. You might need/want to call `context.save()` before calling `clip()` to preserve some other values that will be rolled back by `restore()`.

Comment: Indeed, you first have to call save() before you can call restore(). This is from the documentation of the restore method. "If the stack is empty then nothing is changed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clipping behavior in JavaFX is difficult to say the least. "Remove clipping you say?" How about this.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setHeight(400);
    canvas.setWidth(400);

    GraphicsContext graphics = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    //graphics.save();
    graphics.beginPath();
    graphics.rect(0,0,200,200);
    graphics.clip();
    graphics.setFill(Color.RED);
    graphics.fillOval(100, 100, 200, 200);

    //graphics.restore();
    graphics.beginPath();
    graphics.rect(200,200,200,200);
    graphics.clip();

    graphics.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    graphics.fillOval(100, 100, 200, 200);

    root.getChildren().add(canvas);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

When I do that on my computer, I just get a blue circle. No clipping. Somebody might expect a red quarter of a circle and a blue quarter of a circle. Nope. Un-comment the save and restore calls, and it behaves as expected.